# Flagging statistics omissions

Tags: support, flagging

The picture below shows my question.
426 = 417 + 8 + 1
3 != 2
7 != 3 + 1

As far as I know, there are a few things that can happen to flags.

1. They are marked helpful
2. They are marked disputed
3. They are marked invalid

Where did the missing numbers go?

[image]

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/zd9zi.png

Comment: I do not have such a message. Perhaps something different is going on here?

Comment: @Sathya That's only relevant when `total` > `helpful` + `disputed` + `invalid`. That's not the case here. soandos hasn't been a member long enough for that message to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your other flags were simply ignored or acted on [in the wrong way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109104/151367).

I had the same issue with some flags, they weren't acted on in a flag-resolving way. Some of them were too old for manual correction by moderators.